# is there a way to mantain a variable created in a method outside of it but only available to the class instance?

Tags: java

(first of all, sorry if there are some misspelled words, english is not my main language)

i'm trying to model a product of a market in java and i need an interface for perishable products.
the interface has to be able to set and consult the expiration date, but the class "Product" doesn't have a variable for that. i want to avoid putting thar variable in Product because not all items have expiration dates, and i need to use an interface (even if i want to use an abstract class i think there will be a problem of multiple inheritance).

my idea is creating a variable in the method of the class that implements the interface (setExpDate) and somehow persists and be used as a variable of the instance of the class, is that possible? or should i just go for a variable expDate in Product and not initialize it until is needed?

Comment: If it's a property of an instance, put it in the class ...

Comment: If you're modeling a product then you need to draw a distinction between the product and the item on the shelf in the shop. Interestingly, the relationship is much the same as that between a Java class and an instance of it

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a class `PerishableProduct` that is a subclass of `Product` and has a field `expirationDate`, which `Product` has not. There are other options, but this is the natural and objcet-oriented one, and other ways would just add more complication with no gain that I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an interface for products. Define a getter method for each of its properties.

```
interface Product {
    public UUID getId();
}
```

Define another interface for perishable products. Specify a getter method for each of its additional properties.

```
interface PerishableProduct extends Product {
    public LocalDate getExpirationDate() ;
}
```

Define a product implementation class with the necessary fields. Add [getter method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#Java) implementations as required by the interfaces.

```
class Milk implements PerishableProduct {
    // Member fields. 
    private UUID id;
    private LocalDate expirationDate ;

    // Constructor
    public Milk ( final UUID id , final LocalDate expirationDate ) {
        this.id = id ;
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate ;
    }

    // Implement the interfaces’ methods. 
    public UUID getId() { return this.id ; }  // Required by Product interface. 
    public LocalDate getExpirationDate() { return this.expirationDate ; }  // Required by PerishableProduct interface. 
}
```

---

In real work, we would also be adding methods to override `Object` methods, implementing `Comparable`, etc.

---

If your objects are meant to be read-only (shallowly [immutable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)), then in modern Java we can simplify the code with [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

With records, we drop the `get` prefix on the getter methods. That [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) convention is not used by records. In a record, the implicit getter method has the same name as the property.

```
interface Product { public UUID id(); }
interface PerishableProduct extends Product { public LocalDate expirationDate() ; }
record Milk implements PerishableProduct ( UUID id , LocalDate expirationDate ) {}
```

---

These are basic Java concepts. You should be learning these from a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) or [book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58230342).

Comment: Nice. I know it’s debatable, but depending on needs one may already in the `Product` interface declare a method like `Optional<LocalDate> getExpirationDate()` that in the case of a non-perishable product returns an empty `Optional`. This would allow you to query any product and see whether it’s perishable. Generally `Optional` is considered overkill for getters, though.

Comment: In addition to what's been mentioned, you can add @NotNull annotation to the method parameter. This would make it more readable as well as add basic validation when used is conjunction with a validation library such as hibernate-validator

Answer (score 0):

Just create the variable with a default value of null. Then set it as appropriate. Depending on the use case, you can return a String of the date or a message like "No expiration" if it hasn't been set.

```
class Product { 
    private static LocalDate NO_EXPIRATION = null;
    private LocalDate expirationDate = NO_EXPIRATION;
    
    public void setExpirationDate(LocalDate expDate) {
        expirationDate = expDate;
    }
    public String getExpirationDate() {
        return expirationDate == NO_EXPIRATION ?
                "No expiration" :
                expirationDate.format(<SomeFormat>); // or .toString()
    }
}
```

Or just have a date for everything with the default being a date in the very distant future for non-perishable items.